# Регулярные выражения | Discord Bot | NODE.js | JavaScript | discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Господа, такое дело, делаю антимат для discord бота, чтобы он заменял матные слова на *цензура*, принципе код написан, все отлично, но проблема в том, что бот видит матные слова в безобидных словах, например: "употреБЛЯТЬ" и успешно заменяет это слово на употре*цензура*, как это можно исправить?

Код:

```
let filterwordslist = ["мат", "этомат", "и это мат", "м а т"];

switch (true) {

case message.author.bot: return;

case new RegExp(filterwordslist.join("|")).test(message.content.toLowerCase()):
let edit = message.content.toLowerCase();

for (var i in filterwordslist) {
    edit = edit.replace(new RegExp(filterwordslist[i], "gmi"), "`*цензура*`");
};

message.delete();
message.channel.send("", {
    embed: new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    .setAuthor('FilterWords', message.guild.iconURL)
    .setDescription(`${message.author}: ` + edit)
    });
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```js
let filterwordslist = ["мат", "этомат", "и это мат", "м а т"];

let edit = "мат слово мат м а т немат ЭТОМАТ ЭТОНЕМАТ";

filterwordslist.forEach(item => {
  edit = edit.replace(
    new RegExp(`(^|[^а-я])${item}([^а-я]|$)`, "gmi"),
    "$1`*цензура*`$2"
  );
});

console.log(edit);
```