# анти-мат бот discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

[Я нашёл вот это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/961646/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-discord-bot-node-js-javascript-discord-js)

Но это не совсем то, что мне надо. Мне надо что-бы он удалял только сообщения с матом, а без мата оставлял.Вот что у меня получилось:

```
bot.on('message', async message => {
  if(message.author.id == "748788241867603979"){
    let filterwordslist = ["лох", "пидор", "сука", "блять"];
    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    let args = messageArray.slice(0);
    const [...restArgs] = args;
    const text = restArgs.join(' ');
    let edit = text;

    filterwordslist.forEach(item => {
      edit = edit.replace(
        new RegExp(`(^|[^а-я])${item}([^а-я]|$)`, "gmi"),
        "$1`*цензура*`$2"
      );
    });
    if(сообщение с матом){
      message.delete();
      message.channel.send({
        embed: new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setColor("RANDOM")
          .setAuthor('FilterWords', message.guild.iconURL())
          .setDescription(`${message.author}: ` + edit)
      });
    }
  }
})
```

Вопрос у меня в этом условии:

```
if(сообщение с матом){
```

Comment: Спасибо за правку вопроса, я отозвал голос за закрытие и минус сменил на плюс (теперь вопрос вполне может быть полезен).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127317/discussion-on-question-by------discord-js).

Comment: Границы слов проверять надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по коду, переменная `edit` в результате выполнения метода `forEach` содержит *текст с заменами*; а переменная `text` (выше) - похоже, содержит *нетронутый исходный текст*.
Значит, сравнив значение этих переменных, можно определить наличие замен (а следовательно, и мата) в исходном тексте:

```
/*....*/
filterwordslist.forEach(item => {
  edit = edit.replace(
    new RegExp(`(^|[^а-я])${item}([^а-я]|$)`, "gmi"),
    "$1`*цензура*`$2"
  );
});
if (edit !== text) {
  message.delete();
  /*....*/
}
```

Comment: спасибо тебе, как я сам не додумался.

Comment: Неужели нельзя проверить вхождение без замены?

Comment: меня и так устраивает, а как говорится, работает не трогай.

Comment: @Qwertiy, можно. Заменив `forEach` на метод `some`, в коллбэке которого возвращая результат `(new RegExp(....)).test(edit)`. Это даст незначительный выигрыш в производительности. Стоит ли он простоты изменений (образовательной цели) - по-моему, нет. Оптимизации уже существующего кода, желательно выполнять при необходимости в них. Когда алгоритм реализуется с нуля - другое дело.

Comment: Еще пару спичек сэкономить, поможет однократное инстанцирование массива слов и регулярок из них при запуске приложения. В этом уже начинает играть роль общая архитектура, а не только один отдельно взятый обработчик... и с высокой вероятностью появляется еще больше векторов оптимизации.

Comment: По-моему, можно сделать намного короче, красивее и эффективнее одновременно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, конечно можно. Но это будет уже компромиссом с гибкостью (если выбросить конструктор регулярок).

Answer (score 1):

Вынеси список запрещённых слов в константу вне всех методов:

```
const blacklist = new Set(["слово", "второе", "третье"]);
```

А потом проверяй:

```
if (message.content.match(/[а-яё]/gi)?.some(word => blacklist.has(word))) {
```

Это одно из самых эффективных решений.

---

Если версия ноды не позволяет использовать `?.`, то можно вынести в переменную и сделать 2 проверки, либо написать так:

```
if ((message.content.match(/[а-яё]/gi) || []).some(word => blacklist.has(word))) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (message.content.match(/(?<![а-яё])(плохоеслово|другоеслово|ещё)(?![а-яё])/i)) {
```

Comment: Используя для определения границ слова `\b` (если этот токен в JS работает с кириллицей при флаге `u`) или символьный класс юникода (типа `[^\p{L}]`), можно сделать регулярку попроще и побыстрее.

Comment: Точнее, с классами юникода тут уместнее будет `\P{L}` (инверсный `\p{L}`) - то есть, выражение вида `/(^|\P{L})(слово|ещеслово|...)($|\P{L})/iu` при использовании с методом `test`. Простые проверки буквального соответствия токенам не создают такого количества внутренних циклов как look<behind|ahead>'ы, и в _некоторых_ случаях (без `|`) они выполняются быстрее даже чем одиночный `indexOf` (быстрейшего из методов поиска подстроки в JS).

Comment: ответ без пояснений хуже ответа с пояснениями.

Comment: @yar85, `\b` не работает даже с `u`. По крайней мере, у меня не получилось заставить работать, а кроме `u` подходящих флагов вроде нет. С юникодными категориями хорошая идея - как-то даже не подумал, что так можно. Предпросмотры могут создавать циклы, но в данном случае я не вижу причин, по которым они должны возникнуть и думаю, что существенного влияния на производительность нет, зато мой вариант находит ровно слово - без лишних символов по бокам - в большинстве случаев это хороший стиль.

Comment: @yar85, Например, если понадобится список слов, то при добавлении флага `g` вариант с предпросмотрами будет корректен, а вариант с захватом лишних символов не сможет найти оба слова, если они разделены пробелом. Впрочем, можно отказаться от предпросмотра назад и использовать только вперёд, что решит эту проблему, и понизит совместимость кода до ES5. А в то, что регулярка может быть быстрее `indexOf` я что-то не верю. Есть пример?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, одну простую регулярку объяснять? Она ж и так понятная.

Comment: 1. приведённое регулярное выражение достаточно неординарно. 2. опять возвращаемся к «уловке 22»: тот, кому это выражение понятно без пояснений, вряд ли будет искать ответ на данный вопрос: сам напишет подобное выражение.

Comment: @Qwertiy, _«Например, если понадобится список слов»_ - таким образом можно придумать неограниченное количество сторонних кейсов, к которым код не подходит. Разные задачи предполагают разные решения, и это нормально. Задача вопроса "удалить сообщение если <...>" - даже теоретически не подразумевает получение списка слов, она подразумевает только проверку соответствия критериям. _«А в то, что регулярка может быть быстрее indexOf я что-то не верю. Есть пример?»_ - под рукой нет. Тут на ruSO примерно 2 года был вопрос, где это воспроизводилось... сейчас я его уже вряд ли найду.

Comment: @Qwertiy, сейчас в синтетике проверил скорость поиска - в Хроме преимущество регулярки не воспроизводится, хотя разница не очень существенная (около 13%). Видимо, в том старом вопросе какое-то доп.выражение в коде с `indexOf` сыграло негативную роль... например, [попортить производительность мог `split`](https://jsben.ch/Yhbqk).

Comment: Всяко-разно попробовал, но в _строковом_ регистрозависимом поиске `indexOf` все равно выходит победителем. Скорее всего, я помню неверно, и в старом вопросе поиск был все же со сплитом (то есть, уже не по строке + потери на создание массива), как в бенче по ссылке.